# "Fire and forget" in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssis, ssis-2014

I need to run pairs of packages from one job. First packages needs to run linearly. Second ones in parallel. I want to use configuration table for those packages, and use SSIS foreach container to run those pairs according to configurations. So I need somehow to cause this container not to wait for a second package to finish and run the next pair. One way that I know is to use SQL jobs that can be fired and be forgotten, but that means, that I need to create a job for each pair, but there might be a hundreds of them, so I want to avoid that.

Comment: put them in seperate foreach containers?

Comment: How it will help? I need first package of the first pair to run, after completion, to run the second package of the first pair, then run the first package of the second pair without waiting for completion of the second package of the first pair, and so on.

Comment: Make a second foreach container and increment  by 2?  So foreach 1  execute first pair, foreach 2 starts with second pair, then foreach1 takes 3th pair & foreach2 takes 4th pair?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - how foreach 1 and foreach to are going to run? 
In parallel\linearly?
One iteration of 1 and one of 2?